# Sub figures of different sizes over two column text

Tags: floats, subfloats, two-column

I have two figures of different sizes, one which I want to extend on the full page and the other which I want only on one side of my two column text.

Here is what I a achieve:

[image: Test]

And here is the code I used for that:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth,height=0.1\textheight]{example-image-a}
\subcaption{Figure (a)}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.1\textheight]{example-image-b}
\subcaption{Figure (b)}
\end{figure}
  
\lipsum{}
\end{document}
```

The problem of course, is that the first figure extends over the text, which I do not want. I know how I could make it such that there is no text to the right side of the figure, but then I still want text to be on the right side of Figure B.

Thank you very much in advance!

Ziggy

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Using `\ContinuedFloat` you can have something like this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\lipsum{}
\begin{figure*}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth,height=0.1\textheight]{example-image-a}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.1\textheight]{example-image-b}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Main Figure caption}
\end{figure}
  \lipsum{}

\end{document}
```

This gives this result (on second page):

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much!